# How to remove data in / directory

Tags: linux, directory

I would like to know what is contained in the "/" directory and is it capable of utilizing 50GB. My system all the 50GB allocated to "/" had been utilized. I want to know what to delete if want to utilize the space in an efficient way? I can't see any big files in "/" .

Comment: Well, everything is ultimately under `/`, so... you simply seem to have a full disk. Find out what's using so much space and check if you really need it and delete it if not.

Comment: Much, much, much more information at [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429/80216)  As usual, [Sturgeon's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space doesn't get allocated to directories,
so it's impossible to utilize all the space allocated to a directory. 
Space gets allocated to *filesystems*. 
(If you don't understand what a "filesystem" is,
think of it, to a first approximation, as a *partition*.) 
Filesystems contain directory trees;
a filesystem is generally referenced
by the name of the directory at the top of its tree. 
So, for example, you always have a `/` filesystem;
`/home`, `/usr`, and `/tmp` are frequently separate filesystems. 
Things like `/proc` and `/sys` are special file systems;
sometimes `/dev` and/or `/devices` are, also. 
They don't take up any real disk space at all (or very little),
so let's ignore those for the moment.

To find out what filesystems your system has, run the `mount` command. 
You should get output something like this:

```
/dev/sda5 on  /  type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
/dev/sda6 on /mydata type ext2 (rw)
/dev/sda7 on /backup type vfat (rw)
/dev/sdb on /media/myusb type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

The directory names that appear as the third word on each line
(after the `on`) are the mounted filesystems. 
So anything of the form `/proc/something`
is in the `/proc` filesystem,
anything of the form `/backup/something`
is in the `/backup` filesystem, and so on. 
Everything else under the sun is part of the **`/`** filesystem. 
This gives you a first idea of where you need to be looking.

Also, of course, the `df` command lists your filesystems
along with total size, used space, and available space.

---

```
find / -type d -print
```

will list all the directories in the system. 
If your version of `find` supports it,

```
find / -maxdepth 2 -type d -print
```

will list all the directories in the first two levels;
i.e., it will include `/usr/share` but not `/usr/share/man`.  And

```
find / -xdev  -maxdepth 2 -type d -print
```

or

```
find / -mount -maxdepth 2 -type d -print
```

will list the first two levels of directories ***in the `/` filesystem***. 
This gives you a better idea of where you need to be looking.

---

But, if your system supports this, you can go one better:

```
du -x -d2 /
```

or

```
du --one-file-system --max-depth=2 /
```

will show you the space used in each directory
in the first two levels of directories *in the `/` filesystem*. 
(Note that it shows cumulative totals; e.g., the number shown for `/usr` includes files in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/share`, etc.) 
This can help you find out where your disk space is being used. 
(Sorting it by size is a useful trick
to find the directories that are using the most space.)

Answer (score 0):

The directory `/` contains several directories like `/usr` and `/var` which may contain a lot of data.

Use `du -sh /{usr,var}` to see which directories contain the most data.

You most probably want to have a look into `/var/log` which might contain a lot of old log files, `/var/cache` which might contain a lot of cached files used by your package manager and `/var/tmp` which might contain a lot of temporary files.

Also the homedirectory of the user root resides in `/root` which is on your `/` filesystem. Maybe the root user stored a lot of files into the homedirectory.

There can be some other possibilities but to avoid listing them I advise to start with the above, if that does not clarifies the disk usage to you do `du sh /*` and extract the directories residing on the `/` filesystem and analyze them all.