# Using space available on a different disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-usage, storage

I am using a ubuntu vm on microsoft azure. I am facing a problem with creating new files and data being stored in database. It is throwing an error which says vm out of space. When i run `df -h --total` output in vm is

[image]

`/dev/sdd1` is where all my data is and I am on working on. `/dev/sdc1`  has a lot of space.  How can I make use of that space?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't a problem with `/dev/sda1` instead of `/dev/sdd1`? If you can change mounting points, then mount `/dev/sdc1` to a folder where you need to store your files or database

Comment: can you help me with how to change the mounting points of a folder?

Comment: I guess that it's mounted during boot then it could be done by editing `/etc/fstab`, but the folder which will be new mounting point must be empty.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/sda1` is very important for your OS, so first you have to move some of those files occupying space to `/mnt/datadrive` or `/home/amitbhanja/BertLabs1`. You need to figure out what those files are using `du`.

```
# du -a / | sort -n
```

The last lines has the largest files and directories. Or better to use `ncdu` and check this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux) for more detailed information.

If it turned out to be the database e.g which is on `/var/lib/mysql`, you can configure mysql data directory `datadir` or symlink it to the new location. You need to be careful and always take backups. Moving your own files are preferred to move system files, especially for unexperienced users. Issues could arise if your vm is using `AppArmor` e.g.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the files in `/dev/sda1` using `du` The output of du is printing several 1000s of lines in the console.

Comment: @cvg: I added an example in the answer to make it easier for you