# Aws Ubuntu instance with ebs volume has run out of disk space?how to clear any unwanted files which clear disk space

Tags: disk-usage, logrotate

I am running many python process as services under SystemD. The count could exceed 200 python system services which i found using the below command

```
systemctl list-units --type=service | grep "search string specfic to my created python services" | wc -l
output:245
```

I know that these many services can create so many logs that a disk could be filled.

So I was thinking to setup logrotate and delete logs in a fixed interval. But now I have totally run out of the disk space, and I tried many solutions to clear any space possible and find where space is getting occupied but no luck.

whole 49gb diskspace is used up:

[image]

trying to find what dir occupied more space.

[image]

I had similar problem in gcp, disk got full, but I resolved it by deleting trash listed by this command.

```
sudo find / -type f -printf '%12s %p\n' 2>/dev/null|awk '{if($1>999999999)print $0;}'
```

but I when i am using this the only thing it lists is `/proc/kcrore`,

[image]

I know i can't delete this

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console-output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are oftendifficult to read, and contributors will have to type-copy example content of commands in order to reproduce the problem. Instead, copy-and-paste the console I/O into the question using code formatting tags.

Comment: See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/