# Cumulative size disk usage with du and tree commands

Tags: disk-usage

I need to show my root `/` directory file cumulative size with deep level 1
Its looks easy but I can't run which deserve

tree command doesn't show cumulative size

```
tree --du -h -L 1 
.
├── [   7]  bin -> usr/bin
├── [4.0K]  boot
├── [ 21K]  desktopfs-pkgs.txt
├── [4.2K]  dev
├── [ 12K]  etc
├── [4.0K]  home
├── [   7]  lib -> usr/lib
├── [   7]  lib64 -> usr/lib
├── [ 16K]  lost+found
├── [4.0K]  media
├── [4.0K]  mnt
├── [4.0K]  opt
├── [   0]  proc
├── [4.0K]  root
├── [4.8K]  rootfs-pkgs.txt
├── [ 800]  run
├── [   7]  sbin -> usr/bin
├── [  19]  snap -> /var/lib/snapd/snap
├── [4.0K]  srv
├── [   0]  sys
├── [ 520]  tmp
├── [4.0K]  Untitled Folder
├── [4.0K]  usr
└── [4.0K]  var
```

Also, `du` command

```
du -h -d 1 /
8,0K    /media
du: cannot read directory '/sys/kernel/tracing': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/sys/kernel/debug': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/sys/fs/pstore': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/sys/fs/bpf': Permission denied
0   /sys
166G    /mnt
du: cannot read directory '/run/udisks2': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/wpa_supplicant': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/dir': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/svnserve': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/sudo': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/lightdm': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/lock/lvm': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/systemd/unit-root': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/systemd/inaccessible/dir': Permission denied
1,6M    /run
du: cannot read directory '/home/max/.cache/yay/wine-stable/pkg': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/max/.cache/yay/gnuradio-git/pkg': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/max/.cache/yay/pamac-classic/pkg': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/max/.cache/yay/wine-stable-next/pkg': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/max/.cache/yay/pamac-aur/pkg': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/max/.cache/paru/clone/qm-dfu-util-git/pkg': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/lost+found': Permission denied
146G    /home
.
.
.
Goes so on
```

I need only 1 deep level but `du -h -d 1 /` command shows permission denies. How can I ignore them for the cleanest view I tried to give `root permission` but shows minor errors

```
sudo du -h -d 1 /
8,0K    /media
0   /sys
166G    /mnt
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
1,6M    /run
146G    /home
du: cannot access '/proc/12363/task/12363/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12363/task/12363/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12363/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12363/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
19M /etc
16K /lost+found
0   /dev
49G /usr
41G /var
4,0K    /Untitled Folder
9,1M    /srv
2,6G    /opt
1,8M    /root
51M /tmp
98M /boot
403G    /
```

I glanced many example on web those commands looks great but mine terminal **which Shell: bash 5.1.0 under default Manjaro** looks a little bit away from perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting disk usage, the content of virtual file systems (for instance, on my GNU/Linux: `/dev`, `/proc`, `/run`, `/sys` and `/tmp`) is usually not relevant. Excluding them makes things easier.

Using `du`, if you are fine with only listing the content of the file system mounted on `/` (ignoring that of other mount points), you can run:

```bsh
sudo du -h -d1 -a -x /
```

Or, if you prefer not to use the `-x` ("one file system") option:

```bsh
sudo du -h -d1 -a --exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc \
  --exclude=/run --exclude=/sys --exclude=/tmp /
```

(`-a` makes `du` show regular files as well).

While `tree` can not limit the depth of its output with `-L` *and* also show the full-depth size of directories (i.e. including all the contained subdirectories an files), you can let it produce formatted output and filter it afterwards. For instance, using JSON and `jq`:

```bsh
sudo tree --du -a -x -h -J / | jq 'del(.[]?[]?[]?[]?[]?)'
```

(Unfortunately, `tree`'s JSON output tends to contain malformed bits, making this solution quite unreliable).

You may also refer to [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429/315749) if you are interested in tools other than those mentioned in your question.

Comment: That I was looking disk space where gone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter out the errors by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

```
sudo du -h -d 1 / 2>/dev/null
```

Another possibility without specifying the depth, but using a wildcard instead would be:

```
sudo du -sh /* 2>/dev/null
```