# Debian: maintenance tasks to free tmp folder

Tags: debian, disk-usage

I administrate a server with `Debian 10 Buster`. This server is almost occupied with a `PostgreSQL` database. When I inspect the used/avlaible space in this database with `pgAdmin`, I found 29 Go of full space (data + indexes + sequences + views + functions...). I often do vaccum tasks to keep a clear database.

When I inspect used/avalaible space in the server, I found 58 Go used.

`df -h`

[image]

With the help of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), I made a more specific analyze to found details with [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu), and I found this:

`ncdu -x`

[image]

The `tmp` folder is heavy, almost as the database.

**My questions:**

Is it a regular behaviour for the system to have a such huge `tmp` folder ?

Is there any risks of system corruption to do a manual maintenance of those `du_chunks` ?

Can I do maintenance tasks to clear this folder ? If yes, wich ones ?

Comment: Research: I have found a line `CHUNK_FILE="$TMP_DIR/du_chunk_$RANDOM"` in `dropbox_uploader.sh`.

Comment: I removed files older than a week with `find /tmp -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;` Everything seems to works fine. In theory, these temporary files should be deleted, unless an error has appeared during the execution of `dropbox_uploader.sh`. I will try to understand why with log files.