# What determines the order that `du` runs in?

Tags: filesystems

In a [different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/731200/30828) I discovered that "*There are a few dirs which you should not run du against*", and that "*The output should tell you what has been completed and what the next is causing the hang*". However, it's not possible to determine what "*the next*" would be unless you know the order in which `du` checks directories. **What is that order?** It doesn't appear to be based on name, last modification time, last access time, or creation time (confirmed by checking the output of `du --max-depth=1 2>/dev/null` against `ls --time=[ctime/atime/birth]`), and it's not describe in `man du` or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#du-invocation).

(I recognize that this information isn't necessary in order to resolve my initial problem - I can just try `du` against sets of directories until I find the problematic ones. But I'm curious!)

(Apologies for the overly-broad tag, but there is no specific `du` tag, and it's not possible to submit a question without a tag)

Comment: "The next" is determined by whatever order happens to come out of the filesystem when readdir() is called, it's an implementation detail. There's no real contract or well defined order there. If you require an order, you might consider feeding a list in whatever order you like to du instead of having it iterate files and directories itself.

Comment: Great, thanks! Would you like to submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: FWIW, `ls -f` would likely also display the directory entries in this unsorted order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular order. It lists objects in the order they appear in the directories, essentially random. (This is what makes the comment you are citing wrong — you can't know what will go next just by observing already completed entries.)

The only ordering you could have is that it respects the order of *roots* you've given it at the command line; so, say if you run it like `du /home /var`, it will run through all elements in /home *in random order* and then it will output whatever is in /var *in random order*.

Also, it should be not much of a problem running it through `/proc`.

However, if you want to exclude some directories, there are some switches:

```
       -X, --exclude-from=FILE
              exclude files that match any pattern in FILE

       --exclude=PATTERN
              exclude files that match PATTERN

       -x, --one-file-system
              skip directories on different file systems
```

For instance, `du -x /` will definitely skip /proc and /sys because those are mounted virtual file systems.

Comment: Thanks! I'd come across the exclusion flags, and also the ability to pass a pre-sorted list to `du` - I was just curious about the underlying mechanism.